# removing Duplicate words form a file with two seprators and extension .txt shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a quesiton in shell scripting.

I have one file from which I want to remove duplicate words.
These words are separated by spaces and underscore.

I want to remove **Level_KPLLI_Tpp;** and **Level KPLLI Tpp;**
part from every line by comparing it with content in a same line. so that all of the lines will be in same pattern and become more readable.

But the problem I am facing is, I am able to remove the word KPLLI but word **Tpp** and **Level** is not getting removed as in a line "Level" word is getting as **"/Level**" and "Tpp" is getting as "**Tpp.txt**" which is not correct.

The names can be anything here for example I have taken "Level_KPLLI_Tpp".

How to solve this kind of problem, Please help !!

Thanks in advance !!

INPUT FILE ::

```
065135 Level KPLLI Tpp; 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level KPLLIs Tpp.txt
065138 Level KPLLI Tpp; 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level KPLLIs Tpp.txt;spent;349;ms
065135 Level_KPLLI_Tpp; 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level_KPLLIs_Tpp.txt
065138 Level_KPLLI_Tpp; 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level_KPLLIs_Tpp.txt;spent;349;ms
065137 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/smith/Level1_HLLP.txt
070243 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/smith/Level1_HLLP.txt;spent;6661;ms
```

OUPUT FILE ::

```
065135 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level KPLLIs Tpp.txt
065138 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level KPLLIs Tpp.txt;spent;349;ms
065135 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level_KPLLIs_Tpp.txt
065138 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level_KPLLIs_Tpp.txt;spent;349;ms
065137 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/smith/Level1_HLLP.txt
070243 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/smith/Level1_HLLP.txt;spent;6661;ms
```

Comment: Play with sed without backslashes first and than look to the solutions given.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method , I hope this will help for you

```
 sed 's/\([0-9]\+ \).*\([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\2/' FileName
```

or

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+ \).*\(\([0-9]\{2\}:\)\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\2\4/g' FileName
```

**Output:**

```
065135 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level KPLLIs Tpp.txt
065138 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level KPLLIs Tpp.txt;spent;349;ms
065135 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level_KPLLIs_Tpp.txt
065138 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/name/dire/Level_KPLLIs_Tpp.txt;spent;349;ms
065137 06:35:00 Starting computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/smith/Level1_HLLP.txt
070243 06:35:00 Ending computation; ;/opt/user/con/files/smith/Level1_HLLP.txt;spent;6661;ms
```

Answer (score 1):

This mignt work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 's/ .*;\( ..:..:.. \)/\1/' file
```

Pattern match on the `;` followed by the time and remove the unwanted strings.

Comment: ^1, nothing GNU specific there, will work in any sed.